# ListView not display data in Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm creating a ListView with custom objects of a class within a Fragment and the ListView is blank in the emulator so I'm not totally sure what I'm forgetting. Here are the `onCreateView()` method, the Adapter, the objects, the object class, and the layout file.

onCreateView

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kitchen, container, false);
    add = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
        }
    });
    ArrayList<Ing> listOfIngs = new ArrayList<>();
    IngAdapter adapter = new IngAdapter(getContext(), listOfIngs);
    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return root;

}
```

Adapter

```
public class IngAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ing> {
    IngAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ing> ings) {
        super(context, 0, ings);
    }
}
```

Objects

```
final Ing tomatoSauce = new Ing("Tomato Sauce", 0 ,0);

final Ing chicken = new Ing("Chicken", 0 ,0);

final Ing olives = new Ing("Olives", 0, 0);
```

Object Class

```
public class Ing {

    int init;

    int value;

    String name;

    Ing(String name, int value, int init) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.init = init;
    }
}
```

Layout File

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.lastineindustries.ingredismartv2.Kitchen">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add An Ingredient"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where is `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your list empty. You must add items to the list.Try this code:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kitchen, container, false);
    add = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog();
        }
    });
    ArrayList<Ing> listOfIngs = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfIngs.add(new Ing("test1",1,1));
    listOfIngs.add(new Ing("test2",2,2));
    IngAdapter adapter = new IngAdapter(getContext(), listOfIngs);

    ListView listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return root;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missed this code

```
listOfIngs.add(tomatoSauce);
listOfIngs.add(chicken);
listOfIngs.add(olives);
```

Just put it after you are initializing these objects.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something!

Answer (score 0):

Try add items of ArrayList in constructor of IngAdapter.

Adapter

```
public class IngAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ing> {
    IngAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ing> ings) {          
        Ing tomatoSauce = new Ing("Tomato Sauce", 0 ,0);
        Ing chicken = new Ing("Chicken", 0 ,0);
        Ing olives = new Ing("Olives", 0, 0);

        ings.add(tomatoSauce);
        ings.add(chicken);
        ings.add(olives);

        super(context, 0, ings);
    }
}
```